# Pass args and mount volume at the same time?

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, docker-volume

I have docker image of a console application and this application takes two arguments which are directory paths. Now, when I run the command below to spin up the container with args and also to have access to the volume at the same time, I use following command:

`docker run 9a6 "root/input" "root/Output/" -v /:/root`

It throws following error:

`Could not find a part of the path '/opt/application/root/Norms'.`

where `opt/application` is my workDirectory.I do not have any problems mounting if input and out put paths are hardcoded inside the application. But it sounds like when passed as args, it sounds like I am doing something wrong and when application starts reading the args, it does not look like it is not mounted properly.

What am I doing wrong here? Or may be a better question: "Is this the right way to mount volume and pass the args at he same time?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is you are passing `-v /:/root` as an argument to the `ENTRYPOINT` of your container.

In order to get the behaviour you want you need to mount the volumes before you pass any arguments.

Doing it like this should work:

`docker run -v /:/root 9a6 "root/input" "root/Output/"`